# dput() concatenated vector with no quotes, separated by commas in R

Tags: beginner, r

An oddly specific task - I have a dataframe with columns with values I need to concatenate in order to prepare a query for a website that requires very specific inputs: unquoted strings, separated by commas.  Here's a `dput()` of a subset of the dataframe with the columns needed:

```
d = structure(list(CodeSpace = c(1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 1303L, 
1303L), TagID = c(23041L, 23042L, 23044L, 23046L, 23043L, 23045L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The output I need is:

```
A69-1303-23041, A69-1303-23042, A69-1303-23044, A69-1303-23046, A69-1303-23043, A69-1303-23045
```

I can approximate it (though I end up with a trailing comma) with:

```
cat(paste0(noquote(paste("A69", d$CodeSpace, d$TagID, sep = "-")) , ","))
```

Is there a better (i.e. more principled) way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more conventional way to do that is to use the `collapse` argument of `paste()`:

```
cat(paste(paste("A69", d$CodeSpace, d$TagID, sep = "-"), collapse = ", "))
# A69-1303-23041, A69-1303-23042, A69-1303-23044, A69-1303-23046, A69-1303-23043, A69-1303-23045
```